# how to add reflex comment based on 2 results on Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

There are 2 analytes and each analyte can be Not Detected or Detected

So the scenerios would be:
ANALYTES  RESULTS - database columns
Analyte1   Detected
Analyte2   Detected

Analyte1   Not Detected
Analyte2   Not Detected

Analyte1   Detected
Analyte2   Not Detected

Analyte1   Not Detected
Analyte2   Detected

How can I add different comments based on the different results scenarios with Crystal Syntax (for Crystal reports)?

I've tried doing an (if, then) script but it would just randomly pick an analyte and result from those folders, which is not the solution because the comment would need to be based on the result for the other analyte too.

Answer (score 0):

Your description is a bit vague, but I assume that:

- the table RESULTS has only a single ANALYTES_RESULT column (because if you truly had 2 columns, the solution would be trivial).
- the table RESULTS has a CASE_ID column. And each CASE_ID value has 2 rows providing the two results
- the table RESULTS has a unique key called ID

Use Database Expert to add the table to the report a second time, creating an Alias. Let's call it **RESULTS_2**. Join the 2 tables on:

```
RESULTS.CASE_ID = RESULTS_2.CASE_ID AND RESULTS.ID < RESULTS_2.ID
```

That would give you a single composite record that combines the two results and presents them in 2 columns. The rest is trivial.